# ms access vba code for update records through form

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am new to MS Access 2007 & I know almost nothing about vba. ... I hv a table name F with fields F1, F2, F3, F4, F5  where 1st three are number fields & last two are text fields. In a form with textboxes: txtF1, txtF2, txtF3, txtF4, txtF5 and command button cmdUpdate, I want to update F5 in table F where F1=txtF1, F2=txtF2, F3=txtF3 and F4=txtF4 conditions staisfy. .. Kindly help with complete code.

Comment: Please read the Tour and [ask].

Comment: _Kindly help with complete code_? Do you walk into class with a blank sheet of paper and ask your teacher to give you the answers? Attempt to solve the problem, then come back here if you have a specific issue with your code.

Answer (score 0):

In the cmdUpdate button's on click event, you need to place a procedure that will generate a sql command, then execute it.

```
Private Sub cmdUpdate_Click()

'Create a string variable to hold your sql command string
Dim strSQL As String

'Fill the variable with your sql command, plucking values out of your 
'form as shown using the Me. operator.  When using text values in your 
'string, wrap them with the Chr(34)'s, which will insert quotation marks in 
'your sql string when it's resolved.
strSQL = "UPDATE F SET F.F5 = " & Chr(34) & yourtextvaluehere & Chr(34) & _
            " WHERE F1=" & Me.txtF1 & _
            " AND F2=" & Me.txtF2 & _
            " AND F3=" & Me.txtF3 & _
            " AND F4=" & Chr(34) & Me.txtF4 & Chr(34)

'Execute the sql statement you've built against the database
CurrentDb.Execute strSQL, dbSeeChanges + dbFailOnError

End Sub
```